# htaccess, sub folder rewrite to index.php

Tags: .htaccess

how can I do this?

main link:

```
http://www.domain.com/?link=whatever/something/everythting
```

convert to:

```
http://www.domain.com/whatever/something/everythting
```

I tried with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?link=$1 [L]
```

But not working.

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /?link=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?link=$1 [L]
```

**Edit:**

As @anubhava posted in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029816/htaccess-sub-folder-rewrite-to-index-hphp/11030252#11030252), you should check whether the requested file or directory exists or not in a RewriteCond.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ index.php?link=$1 [L]
```